# Npm workspace installation failure on Ubuntu 22. But works on Windows and Mac OS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install, npm-workspaces

I use npm workspaces. In code I have 2 folders `@applications/*` that depends on `@packages/*` .
While I install packages for `npm install --workspace=@applications/archivist --include-workspace-root --verbose` that contain `@packages/duct` and `@packages/authentication` and they have own  `postinstall` script to `build` application with `tsc`.

```
{
  "name": "@gravity/icebreaker",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=19",
    "npm": ">=9"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "applications/*",
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.30.0",
    "tsx": "^3.12.6",
    "turbo": "^1.6.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.3"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "name": "@applications/archivist",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "./build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --build --clean && tsc && tsc-alias",
    "postinstall": "npm run prisma:generate && npm run build",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@packages/authentication": "*",
    "@packages/duct": "*",
    ...
  },
}
```

```
{
  "name": "@packages/authentication",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --build --clean && tsc",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
  }
}
```

```
{
  "name": "@packages/duct",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --build --clean && tsc",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
  }
}
```

On `mac` and `windows` when I run  `npm install --workspace=@applications/archivist --include-workspace-root --verbose` `npm` successfully installs all the nested packages and runs `postinstall` scripts. However, when running this process through **Ubuntu**, it produces an error as shown below.

Full Logs: [ubuntu_logs.txt](https://github.com/npm/cli/files/11238789/ubuntu_logs.txt)
*Chunk of error:*

````
2023-04-14T16:11:00.1958263Z npm info run @applications/archivist@0.0.1 postinstall applications/archivist npm run prisma:generate && npm run build
2023-04-14T16:11:00.2156498Z npm info run @packages/authentication@0.0.1 postinstall packages/authentication npm run build
2023-04-14T16:11:03.2436518Z npm info run @packages/authentication@0.0.1 postinstall { code: 0, signal: null }
2023-04-14T16:11:03.2437189Z npm info run @packages/duct@0.0.1 postinstall packages/duct npm run build
2023-04-14T16:11:06.8146136Z npm info run @packages/duct@0.0.1 postinstall { code: 0, signal: null }
2023-04-14T16:11:07.2289043Z npm info run @applications/archivist@0.0.1 postinstall { code: 1, signal: null }
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6921115Z npm verb stack Error: command failed
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6922207Z npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/19.9.0/x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:53:27)
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6922780Z npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6923226Z npm verb stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6923722Z npm verb stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6924456Z npm verb pkgid @applications/archivist@0.0.1
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6924828Z npm verb cwd /home/runner/work/Icebreaker/Icebreaker
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6925411Z npm verb Linux 5.15.0-1035-azure
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6927214Z npm verb node v19.9.0
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6929825Z npm verb npm  v9.6.3
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6939186Z npm ERR! code 1
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6941335Z npm ERR! path /home/runner/work/Icebreaker/Icebreaker/applications/archivist
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6958281Z npm ERR! command failed
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6960583Z npm ERR! command sh -c npm run prisma:generate && npm run build
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6962601Z npm ERR! > @applications/archivist@0.0.1 prisma:generate
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6964027Z npm ERR! > prisma generate
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6965265Z npm ERR! 
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6966633Z npm ERR! Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6967923Z npm ERR! 
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6969613Z npm ERR! ✔ Generated Prisma Client (4.12.0 | library) to ./node_modules/.prisma/client in 88ms
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6971251Z npm ERR! You can now start using Prisma Client in your code. Reference: https://pris.ly/d/client
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6972596Z npm ERR! ```
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6974230Z npm ERR! import { PrismaClient } from './node_modules/.prisma/client'
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6975705Z npm ERR! const prisma = new PrismaClient()
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6976992Z npm ERR! ```
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6978199Z npm ERR! 
2023-04-14T16:11:07.6979578Z npm ERR! > @applications/archivist@0.0.1 build
2023-04-14T16:11:07.7036615Z npm ERR! > tsc --build --clean && tsc && tsc-alias
2023-04-14T16:11:07.7037189Z npm ERR! 
2023-04-14T16:11:07.7059979Z ##[error]npm ERR! src/services/duct.service.ts(9,8): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@packages/duct' or its corresponding type declarations.
2023-04-14T16:11:07.7069502Z npm ERR! npm verb cli /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/19.9.0/x64/bin/node /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/19.9.0/x64/bin/npm
2023-04-14T16:11:07.7069924Z npm ERR! npm info using npm@9.6.3
2023-04-14T16:11:07.7070251Z npm ERR! npm info using node@v19.9.0
2023-04-14T16:11:07.7070677Z npm ERR! npm info found workspace root at /home/runner/work/Icebreaker/Icebreaker
````

---

Example of mac logs with success.
[mac_logs.txt](https://github.com/npm/cli/files/11238791/mac_logs.txt)

#### Expected Behavior

When I install packages with workspaces, it runs `install` and  `postinstall` on nested packages firstly and then on top package.

#### Steps To Reproduce

You can upload this repository and test it: https://github.com/md-gravity/Icebreaker/pull/7
Switch to: [join-to-the-room-from-web](https://github.com/md-gravity/Icebreaker/tree/join-to-the-room-from-web)
Run: `npm install --workspace=@applications/archivist --include-workspace-root --verbose`

#### Environment

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

```
; node bin location = /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/19.9.0/x64/bin/node
; node version = v19.9.0
; npm local prefix = /home/runner/work/Icebreaker/Icebreaker
; npm version = [9](https://github.com/md-gravity/Icebreaker/actions/runs/4706804135/jobs/8348279786#step:4:10).6.3
; cwd = /home/runner/work/Icebreaker/Icebreaker
; HOME = /home/runner
```

Mac 13.2.1 (22D68) where installation is**ok**:

```
npm config ls
; "builtin" config from /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc

prefix = "/opt/homebrew" 

; "user" config from /Users/dormammun/.npmrc

//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken = (protected) 

; node bin location = /usr/local/bin/node
; node version = v19.9.0
; npm local prefix = /Users/dormammun/code/md-gravity/Icebreaker
; npm version = 9.6.4
; cwd = /Users/dormammun/code/md-gravity/Icebreaker
; HOME = /Users/dormammun
; Run `npm config ls -l` to show all defaults.
```